# Creating objects that are owned by class A in class B where B doesn't know of A

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a question about design. There is class A that owns a map of objects of type Foo. Objects of A create Foo objects and store them in the map, but when a certain indication comes, I want to do some work in class B and create further Foo objects there. A is aware of B and delegates the task to it, but not the other way round. Foo objects created in B still need to go into the map in A.

Possible solutions:

1. Return a map of shared_ptrs to created objects from a method in B.
2. Pass the map from A to a method in B as a non-const reference.

Somehow, I have a feeling that both of these approaches are bad and class B shouldn't really create objects that it doesn't own. Is there some design pattern that would help in this situation? I was thinking about some factory, but it's just adding a proxy to the problem and I don't really think it helps much. Or maybe I should get rid of class B altogether and have all the logic in A? The problem here, however, is that I don't want A to do too much.

Comment: can you return from B vector of created objects and then insert these objects into map in A ?

Comment: Could you give a bit more information on what the actual problem is you're trying to solve with this design? Your question currently focuses on how to make a particular design work rather than explaining what you're trying to accomplish. It will be hard to suggest a better approach without know what the actual problem is…

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an appropriate handler, similar to the following:

```
class B
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void execute(T newObjectHandler)
    {
        Foo* foo = new Foo();
        newObjectHandler(foo);
        executeTask(foo);
    }
};

void A::executeTask()
{
    myB->executeTask([this](Foo* foo) { /* insert into map */ });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going for your 1. solution is ok to me as long as the ownership of Foo objects created from class B and transferred to class A is clearly stated because deletion will take place in/from A.

Merging two maps shouldn't be a big deal.

It has a strong advantage compared to your 2. solution:
 - there is no coupling with A's internal map > return type can vary independently in both A or B, allowing you to use the same from another class C in the future which could hold Foo objects in let's say a `vector<Foo>`